# ViewPagerAdapter in android studio only displays one fragment instead of three

Tags: android

I am trying to switch between three tabs using getItem(), but only the first fragment shows in the three tabs. My getItem code is given below .

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     // Which Fragment should be dislpayed by the viewpager for the given position
    // In my case we are showing up only one fragment in all the three tabs so we are
    // not worrying about the position and just returning the TabFragment
    if(position == 0){
        TabFragment tab1 = new TabFragment();
        return tab1;
    }else if(position == 1){
        InboxFragment tab2 = new InboxFragment();
        return tab2;
    }else {
        StarFragment tab3 = new StarFragment();
        return tab3;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;           // As there are only 3 Tabs
}

}
```

Comment: are you setting the adapter to the ViewPager?

Comment: yes........check the full code

Comment: That's only the adapter, where are you using it? Please, check out my answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're setting your adapter to the viewPager. You should be doing something like this.

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment(), "Fragment 1");
adapter.addFragment(new InboxFragment(), "Fragment 2");
adapter.addFragment(new StarFragment(), "Fragment 3");
mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Also, your adapter could look like this:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
    {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```